# Mongomapper Foreign Key?

Tags: mongodb, mongomapper, padrino

I'm currently using Mongomapper within a Padrino project where I'm importing data from an external source. The main object (`Application`) has two associated document types, `Activity` and `Notice`.

However, I'd like to specify the foreign key myself, rather than use the internal Mongo ID, as the foreign key is in the data export, which I import via a rake task.

I've tried an `EmbeddedDocument`, but this causes issues as I have to delete all the associated data, rather than updating it, which isn't ideal.

I've tried the following, but without any luck:

```
class Application
  include MongoMapper::Document
  ensure_index [[:latlng, '2d']]

  key :refval, String
  key :pkeyval, String
  key :applicantname, String
  key :latlng, Array
  key :address, String
  key :occupier, String
  key :type, String
  key :casetype, String
  key :tradingname, String
  key :closingdate, Date
  key :recieveddate, Date
  key :details, String
  key :usetype, String
  key :status, String
  key :validfrom, Date
  timestamps!

  many :activities
  many :notices  
end

class Activity
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :keyval, String
  key :pkeyval, String
  key :type, String  
  key :cycle, String
  key :open, String
  key :close, String

  belongs_to :application, :foreign_key => :pkeyval
end

class Notice
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :keyval, String
  key :pkeyval, String
  key :recieveddate, Date
  key :startdate, Date
  key :enddate, Date
  key :days, String  
  key :hours, String
  key :activities, Array

  belongs_to :application, :foreign_key => :pkeyval
end
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoMappers's [Associations documentation](http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/associations.html) is a bit light on this, but there's an example to be found in the [test_associations](https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/blob/master/test/functional/test_associations.rb) functional test. The `:foreign_key` definition should be specified on `many` instead of `belongs_to`.

Comment: Yup, that worked, thanks! You're right, the documentation is a bit sketchy to say the least on that point. One extra thing I had to do was to override the primary key on my Application object by changing `key :refval, String` to `key :_id, String`